# Publishing JAX-RS endpoints with pax-web

Tags: java, jax-rs, osgi, karaf, pax-web

I have REST endpoints published in OSGi container (Karaf) using `javax.ws.rs` annotations. HttpService is created by pax-web, and jax-rs services are published by `com.eclipsesource.jaxrs/publisher`.

In order to use this publisher, a quite monstrous feature was forged (copied somewhere from internet):

```
<feature name="jersey-karaf-feature" description="Jersey karaf feature" version="2.2.0">
    <feature prerequisite="false" dependency="true">http</feature>
    <bundle start-level="36">mvn:org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet/2.22.2</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="36">mvn:org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-sse/2.22.2</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="36">mvn:org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-multipart/2.22.2</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="36" dependency="true">mvn:org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet-core/2.22.2</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="36" dependency="true">mvn:org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-common/2.22.2</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="36" dependency="true">mvn:org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged/jersey-guava/2.22.2</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="36" dependency="true">mvn:org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server/2.22.2</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="36" dependency="true">mvn:org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client/2.22.2</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="36" dependency="true">mvn:org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-jaxb/2.22.2</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="33" dependency="true">mvn:org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-api/2.4.0-b34</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="33" dependency="true">mvn:org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-locator/2.4.0-b34</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="33" dependency="true">mvn:org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-utils/2.4.0-b34</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="33" dependency="true">mvn:org.glassfish.hk2/osgi-resource-locator/1.0.1</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="33" dependency="true">mvn:org.glassfish.hk2.external/javax.inject/2.4.0-b34</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="33" dependency="true">mvn:org.glassfish.hk2.external/aopalliance-repackaged/2.4.0-b34</bundle>
    <bundle dependency="true">mvn:javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.2</bundle>
    <bundle dependency="true">mvn:javax.validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final</bundle>
    <bundle dependency="true">mvn:javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0.1</bundle>
    <bundle dependency="true">mvn:org.javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA</bundle>
    <bundle dependency="true">mvn:org.jvnet.mimepull/mimepull/1.9.6</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="80">mvn:com.eclipsesource.jaxrs/publisher/5.3.1</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="80">mvn:javax.ws.rs/jsr311-api/1.1.1</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="80">mvn:org.eclipse.persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.moxy/2.6.4</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="80">mvn:org.eclipse.persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.core/2.6.4</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="80">mvn:javax.validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="80">mvn:org.glassfish/javax.json/1.0.4</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="80">mvn:org.eclipse.persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa/2.6.4</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="80">mvn:org.eclipse.persistence/javax.persistence/2.1.1</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="80">mvn:org.eclipse.persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.asm/2.6.4</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="80">mvn:org.eclipse.persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql/2.6.4</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="80">mvn:org.eclipse.persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.antlr/2.6.4</bundle>
</feature>
```

It generally works, but when I've tried to [register event listener as described in wiki](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxweb/Listeners), the listener was never called. Another issue is the amount of libraries in the feature with 'magic numbers' as start levels, and potential problems by platform upgrade.

Do pax-web have a mechanism for publishing jax-rs endpoints, which I could use instead that forged feature? What do I need to activate, so that my endpoints would be published?

Comment: To the final question, not yet. 
It's work in Progress concerning registering jax-rs endpoints, as that part of the OSGi spec isn't fully specified yet. 
As one of the maintainers, I just can say, we love contributions :)

Answer (score 0):

CXF is an option for publishing REST endpoints. An example can be found at https://github.com/apache/cxf-dosgi/tree/master/samples/rest .

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the PAX-Web [source](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web) and [documentation](http://ops4j.github.io/pax/web/SNAPSHOT/User-Guide.html) (see [User-Guide](http://ops4j.github.io/pax/web/SNAPSHOT/User-Guide.html) and [Developer-Guide](http://ops4j.github.io/pax/web/SNAPSHOT/Developer-Guide.html)) it does not appear to include support for [JAX-RS](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxrs.htm) (Java API for RESTful Web Services), or [JSR 311](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=311).

There are, however, a number of other [options](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tutorial:_Exposing_a_Jax_REST_service_as_an_OSGi_Remote_Service) that can be used to expose JAX-RS endpoints in OSGi, such as RESTeasy, Jersey, Apache CXF and [others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services). Hopefully one of them can be used to improve the architecture you describe. Of the various options, the [CXF implementation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/restful-services.html) seems to be the best documented and is fairly easy to integrate with OSGi, at least based on my experience.